# Amplifier and a source current

Tags: amplifier

We have some sinus signal at the input and at the output we have offset equal to \$5V\$ and sin wave with \$A=0.5V\$. Calculate \$R_C\$. What will happen with the output voltage (DC and AC), if \$C_E\$ is short-circuited?

[image]

Calculating \$R_C\$ is simple:

\$E_C-I_CR_C=5V\\
15-2mA\cdot R_C=5V\rightarrow R_C=5k\Omega\$

But I have no idea what will happen if we replace \$C_E\$ with \$0\Omega\$ resistance

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80157/discussion-on-question-by-santaxl-amplifier-and-a-source-current).

Comment: The answer depends on how accurately you are willing to model the BJT. Is it completely off for Vbe<Vth or are you considering the exponential characteristic? In the latter case when Vs is positive and reaches 0.5V, you are nearing the knee of the Vbe-Ib characteristic, and you'll end up with a very distorted output waveform (I wouldn't even call that spikes, they are more like bumps).